# In elastic APM does @CaptureTransaction create a new tab for external calls

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, javaagents, apm, elastic-apm

for the code below I wanted to create a new tab which would store all the external method calls and would be aggregated, but I am not getting any such results.

```
@CaptureTransaction(value = "Task")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you need new "Transaction type"?

If yes, so you should set `type` annotation parameter.

But @CaptureTranscation annotation work [in case](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/master/public-api.html#api-capture-transaction):

```
Note that this only works when there is no active transaction on the same thread.

    value: The name of the span. Defaults to ClassName#methodName
    type: The type of the transaction. Defaults to request
```